# Persian letters should start from the left like English

Tags: text

This is my original text
یه لحظه خودم رو گم کردم

And I need to be able to convert in this way
مدﺮﮐ ﻢﮔ ور مدﻮﺧ ﻪﻈﺤﻟ ﻪﻳ

Any way you say, I tried, but I didn't get the result, I did all the work in notpad.
If there is a software available for this task, I would be grateful if you could introduce it, or if you know a way to do it in notpad++
sorry my bad english

Answer (score 1):

The `log2vis` function from the `pyfribidi` Python package is able to convert right-to-left Persian text to the left-to-right form:

```py
from pyfribidi import log2vis

def rtl_to_ltr_persian(text):
    """Convert a Persian text string from RTL to LTR orientation."""
    return log2vis(text)
```

**Full script**:

```py
"""Convert a right-to-left Persian string from a text file to left-to-right form and optionally write the result to a new file.

Usage:
    persian_rtl_to_ltr.py <input_file> [-o <output_file>]

Example:
    $ python persian_rtl_to_ltr.py input.txt -o output.txt
"""
import argparse
from pyfribidi import log2vis

def rtl_to_ltr_persian(text):
    """Convert a Persian text string from RTL to LTR orientation."""
    return log2vis(text)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert a right-to-left Persian string from a text file to left-to-right form.')
    parser.add_argument('input_file', type=str, help='Name of the input file containing text to mirror.')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output_file', type=str, help='Name of the output file to store left to right text.')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    with open(args.input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        original_text = infile.read()

    mirrored_text = rtl_to_ltr_persian(original_text)

    if args.output_file:
        with open(args.output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            outfile.write(mirrored_text)
    else:
        print(mirrored_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Result**:
ﻡﺩﺮﮐ ﻢﮔ ﻭﺭ ﻡﺩﻮﺧ ﻪﻈﺤﻟ ﻪﯾ

**Prerequities**:

- Python 3.7 or higher
- The `pyfribidi` package (install it via `pip install pyfribidi`)

**Usage**:

```
persian_rtl_to_ltr.py <input_file> [-o <output_file>]
```

Save your Persian text somewhere as a text file (like input.txt), then save this script as persian_rtl_to_ltr.py, and run it from the command line. Specify an output file (like output.txt) to obtain the left-to-right version of the text.

**Examples**:

```
python persian_rtl_to_ltr.py input.txt
```

```
python persian_rtl_to_ltr.py input.txt -o output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend, let me test and I will tell you the result

Comment: you are best love you friend please accept my thank ❤️❤️

Comment: Dear friend, I tried very hard, but I could not execute your script because I don't know much about programming. If it is possible, you can put everything in a zip file and upload it. Give me the download link and I will download it. I really apologize to you.  I will disturb you

Comment: my friend i dont know how install pyfribidi and what version of payton install im install version 3 please zip all file to zip file and send me link very very sorry my bad english

Comment: Dear friend, hello again, this method that you said is fundamentally problematic. I downloaded and installed Python version 3.0.0, but it cannot be installed using the pip method. I have been trying for a long time. I told you that I am a beginner. Please show me a way.  I really need this thanks

Comment: Please make a video of the zero to one hundred installation and setup of this program along with the installation of Python and pip and.. for Windows 10 and put the link on YouTube for me. im very sorry to disturb

Comment: Feel free to copy this notebook and run it in Google Colab if it saves you the trouble: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YH74uJk-aW9RK4Sj14CiYDuVUl7cAmXM?usp=sharing

Comment: i found this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_cjdCCoEcv4fcJMnq7Yz69nSAbOjBpn/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: dear noah i dont have reputation for chat

Comment: this https://ibb.co/spTTgnf

Comment: Thank you, my friend, it shows two errors, there is also an error wheel

Comment: It doesn't work. My friend doesn't work. I did everything you said, but it gives the same error again when installing pyfibidi.

Comment: https://ibb.co/TYdbyjQ

Comment: Yes, I restarted it several times, dear Noah, can you tell me any other way for my problem, other than Python?

Comment: Which version of Python do you use for this?

Comment: I ticked all the boxes and downloaded about 20 GB, but it didn't work, it gives the same error when installing

Comment: Dear Noah, I'm sorry to disturb you, I really need this, please think for me

Comment: @Omid Sorry but I'm on Stack Overflow to discuss programming questions not to troubleshoot Windows software installation issues. What I can tell you is if you can't figure out the VS build tools issue, you could follow documentation online to install Windows subsystem for linux (WSL) and set that up with Python/pyfribidi. I can't assist with further setup/installation questions, but good luck.

Comment: I will try a little more, I couldn't. I will install Linux. I really thank you

Comment: Hello, I was able to fix the first code you gave with one update without the need for the pyfribidi package, thank you.